# Finding roots of $A_1 \cos\left(k_1 \theta +\phi_1\right) + A_2 \cos\left(k_2 \theta +\phi_2\right)= 0$

Tags: trigonometry, roots

I'm trying to find the roots of this equation
$$
A_1 \cos\left(k_1 \theta +\phi_1\right) + A_2 \cos\left(k_2 \theta +\phi_2\right) = 0
$$

I've found many solutions for special cases when the phase shift, frequency or amplitude are the same, but is there a set of closed form roots in the general case?

**EDIT** My specific case of interest is $k_1 = 1$, $k_2 = 2$ but also interested in where general solutions are possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you need numerical methods. Even when$$A_1=A_2=1,\,\phi_1=\phi_2=0,\,k_1=1,\,k_2\in\Bbb N,$$the above is equivalent to solving arbitrarily high-degree polynomials in $\cos\theta$. In particular, radical solutions are unavailable for even $k_2\ge6$.

Edit: the recently requested special case $k_1=1,\,k_2=2$ is tractable: with $z:=\exp i\theta$ we want to solve$$0=A_1(e^{i\phi_1}z+e^{-i\phi_1}/z)/2+A_2(e^{i\phi_2}z^2+e^{-i\phi_2}/z^2)/2,$$which simplifies to a quartic in $z$, [which we can solve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solution).

Comment: For $k_1=1$, $k2=2$ what is the polynomial? I broke it out and got a quartic equation but might have missed something more straightforward here. Thanks!

Comment: @StackG The case $k_2=2$ is actually fairly easy: the problem is then $2\cos^2\theta+\cos\theta-1=0$. For arbitrary $k_2$, [you can derive the polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) (you will also need Pythagoras), but *solving* it is the challenge.

Comment: I only see how you arrive at that without the phase shift? Any chance you could expand the answer slightly to show how you deal with that?

Comment: @StackG I just noticed your edit. I've edited my answer to acknowledge the result you found when we also have a phase shift; it includes a link to how to solve quartic equations. But as I said, more generally the problem requires numerical methods.

Comment: Thanks greatly appreciated!